# How to externally provide mysql host to spring boot while executing JAR

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I have a java Spring boot project which uses a MySQL database. I have the following `application.properties` file to specify the MySQL url, user and password:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}
spring.datasource.username=${MYSQL_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
```

Using this property file, I can run the application from Eclipse if I edit the run configurations and set the values of `DB_HOST`, `DB_PORT`, `DB_NAME`, `MYSQL_USER` and `MYSQL_PASSWORD` in the Environment tab and run it.. everything works fine.

But now I want to run it on the server, by generating a JAR and passing these values from command line to the Jar during run time. So, I created a Jar file like this:

```
/gradlew clean build bootJar -DDB_HOST=mock -DDB_PORT=mock -DDB_NAME=mock \
-Dmysql_user=mock \
-Dmysql_password=mock
```

this successfully generates the executable Jar file.. then I try to run the generated jar file like this:

```
java -jar build/libs/MyApplication.jar -Ddb_host=localhost \
-Ddb_port=3306 \
-Ddb_name=my_db \
-Dmysql_user=root \
-Dmysql_password=root
```

but it gives the following error:

```
...
Failed to parse the host:port pair '${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}'
...
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${DB_PORT}"
...
```

Which means that it is not actually replacing the values during runtime.

How do I fix this?

**Edit**: I also tried to open up the jar using archive utility and saw the `application.properties` file.. it contains the following line:

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}`

which means that these values should have been updated during runtime. but it isn't

Comment: Just don't include those entries in `application.properties` and set `-Dspring.datasource.username` directly. In the failure case, check whether you need to put those properties before the `-jar` clause.

Comment: Tried that and tried giving the -D part before -jar too.. didn't work. This time it gave the error:

`java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

So, I think that it did not take these values at all from the commandline.

Comment: You can try adding these properties to an external file and using it in a Spring config class using @PropertySource. You can also add these in environment variables depending on how you are deploying your application.

Comment: Using configuration profiles would be the bestpractice here i think. then run those profiles or inject them with environmentvariables (without ${..} stuff) in your app.properties

Comment: `db_host` isn't the same as `DB_HOST`. Use uppercase in your `-D` parameters.

Comment: Thanks, @M.Deinum just realized that. changed to uppercase everywhere, but that didn't work either.. eventually switched to setting them programatically using a datasource config class.

Comment: Have you tried passing them as arguments instead of properties? So instead of `-D` use `--`? `--db_host=<hostame>`.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this? I have same issue. I am manually configured datasource by @Bean but when I run jar it give me an error.

Comment: added solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was eventually able to get this to work by adding a `DatasourceConfig` class and setting the values programatically.

I removed all the `spring.datasource.*` values from my `application.property` file and then created a new class:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class DatasourceConfig {

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setUrl(System.getProperty("MYSQL_URL"));
    dataSource.setUsername(System.getProperty("MYSQL_USER"));
    dataSource.setPassword(System.getProperty("MYSQL_PASSWORD"));
    return dataSource;
  }

}
```

This allows you to configure the datasource, username and password externally as VM arguments at runtime.

The values `MYSQL_URL`,`MYSQL_USER`,`MYSQL_PASSWORD` are passed onto the `gradle` command while building like this:

```sh
./gradlew clean build bootJar -DMYSQL_URL=mock -DMYSQL_USER=mock -DMYSQL_PASSWORD=mock
```

, and similarly to the `java` command while running the jar like this:

```sh
java -jar build/libs/MyApplication.jar -DMYSQL_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db -DMYSQL_USER=root -DMYSQL_PASSWORD=root
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to expose those Fields as Environment Variables before running the jar.

For Linux:

```
$ export DB_HOST=localhost
$ export DB_PORT=3306
$ export DB_NAME=my_db
$ export MYSQL_USER=root
$ export MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
$ java -jar build/libs/MyApplication.jar
```